# Echo the values from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to MySQL, and I'm having some trouble echoing the values from a table. For the code I have here, the output is totally blank. Where am I going wrong? Is it with the loop?

```
<?php    
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;


    $con = mysqli_connect ();
    //Check Connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $table = "CREATE TABLE info (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, city CHAR(40), country CHAR(40))" or die(mysql_error());

    $table = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO info (city, country) VALUES ($a, $b)) or die(mysql_error()") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM info") or die(mysql_error());  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        echo $row['city'];
        }

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`? Notice the "i".

Comment: I just noticed that too, but even after I change it, the output doesn't work, unfortunately. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Since you want to use `mysqli_assoc` here anyway, I'd also suggest using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of _array(). But I don't think that will solve your issue here.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are getting results. Try putting `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` before your while loop. Is it greater then 0?

Comment: I'm sorry, Tudor, but I had to roll-back your edit.  If you have another question.. ask another question.  Don't edit the original, then it is lost.  What you did is also known as a chameleon question.. and those aren't really appreciated here(a question that keeps changing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different extensions.  What you want, as others have said, is [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

On top of that, unless I'm mistaken.. you don't actually connect to any database.  As noted in the documentation, you have to [put connection information in the object when you call it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)(although this is optional if you just want the object, and don't want to connect just yet).

Comment: I don't know why it was mysql instead of mysqli. Either way, the problem is still there after I change to the right one...  Thoughts?

Comment: @TudorManole Did you erase your connection information for your question, or are you just calling the connect method without actually supplying it any parameters?

Comment: That must be it. As I said, I'm very new to MySQL!

Comment: @TudorManole At least you're using that instead of the depcrecated functions.  :)

Comment: @TudorManole Also, please consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem, when you are able.

Comment: @TudorManole If you need further help, I'll do my best to provide, though be warned, I am unfamiliar with mysqli.